# Dropdown fields in multipage forms ejs, nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I have a multi-page form with several dropdown fields. The first form page is called "add-style" and the second is called "add-player". How do I store the variable from `options` field in the first form into "style" table so that the `Station_Type` dropdown in the second form page will be populated with only a selected few values? For example, if the user inputs 'A' for the options field, only values 'Station1' and 'Station2' will be populated in the Station_Type dropdown. If the user inputs 'B' for the options field, only option 'Station3' will be populated in the Station_Type dropdown for user to select. There are other fields in the second form as well. When user submits the second form, the records will be stored in "lineid" table. I have a "station" table with columns `options` and `Station_Type` stored in MySQL which stores the mapping of 'options' with its respective 'Station_Type' values. This is an example of table in MySQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uDV7vH1XqufCT2cFsvXi1r/2.

This is my "add-style" form ejs code:

```
    <form class="add-style-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="options">Options</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="options" id="options" placeholder="options" required>
        </div>

        <button style="height:30px;width:100px;padding:0;font-size: 12px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Add Style</button>
    </form>
```

This is my "add-player" form ejs code:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Station_Type">Station_Type</label>
                <select name="Station_Type" class="form-control" name="Station_Type" id="Station_Type" autocomplete="off">
                
                <!-- for loop code start -->
                <% for(var i=0; i < drecord.length; i++) { %>
                    <option value="<%= drecord[i].options %>"><%= drecord[i].options %></option>
                    <% } %>
                <!-- for loop code end -->
                </select>
            </div>
```

This is my .js file:

```
    addStylePage: (req, res) => {
        res.render('add-style.ejs', {
            title: "Welcome | Add a new style",
            message: ''
        });
    },

    addStyle: (req, res) => {
        
        let options = req.body.options;

        let query2 = "INSERT INTO `style` (options) VALUES ('" + options + "')";
      

            db.query(query2, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                res.redirect('/line');
            });
    },

    addPlayerPage: (req, res) => {

    let myQuery = "SELECT options FROM style;" // query for the dropdown but now it shows all options instead of selected options based on the previous form field 


    db.query(myQuery, function(err, result) {

                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err); // check if query have error
                }
                res.render('add-player.ejs', { 
                    title: "Welcome | Add a new transaction",
                    message: '',
                    drecord: result // setting result reference for ejs
                });
           
        });
},

addPlayer: (req, res) => {
    
    let playerId = req.params.id;
    let Station_Type = req.body.Station_Type;
    let clothes_name = req.body.clothes_name;

   
    let query = "INSERT INTO `lineid` (id, Station_Type, clothes_name) VALUES (NULL, '" + Station_Type + "', '" + clothes_name + "')"; 


            db.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }                
        
            });  
            res.redirect('/line'); 
},
```

Comment: `add-style` is suppose to be the first selection, right? Are you creating a new style or selecting from an existing style because the form is doing `INSERT` instead of `SELECT`..

Comment: I am trying to model a clothes factory data collection system. In the first stage, I need to insert a record of the style then followed by the second stage where i insert  the line number as well as station type. Every style will have their individual set of station types so the downdown list for station type will change according to the style the user inserted in the first stage. I have a table in MySQL mapping the style with their respective station types. Thanks!

Comment: To understand more, can you update this fiddle with all the related tables in your database? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uDV7vH1XqufCT2cFsvXi1r/0 I've created a few tables in there as example. You can create new schemas or edit the existing. Once you've done, click the 'Update' button on top then copy the new link and paste it into your question.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle in my question. Thanks!